# Copy&Swap idiom warning : recursive on all control paths, function will cause runtime stack overflow

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

It's the first time I practically implement the Copy&Swap idiom. But I get this warning at compilation, with Microsoft VS2013:

> warning C4717: 'std::swap' : recursive on all
>   control paths, function will cause runtime stack overflow

I try to get when/where the guilty recursion do happen, but I cannot grasp it.
What I'm doing wrong. What can be corrected ?

```
class A
{
private:
    SmartPtr m_sp = nullptr;

public:
    A(){}

    ~A(){}

    A(const A& other)
    {       
        m_sp = other.m_sp;    
    }

    A(A&& other)
    {
        std::swap(*this, other);
    }

    A& operator=(A other)
    {
        std::swap(other, *this);
        return *this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tip: use your debugger. Call the function you get the warning for. Use breakpoints, and continue until you're in a few nested calls. Inspect the stack trace to see the infinite recursion in detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to implement your own swap function. `std::swap` will call the assignment operator. Which will call `std::swap`. Which will call the assignment operator. Which will...

```
class A
{
    // as before

    swap(A& other) { std::swap(m_sp, other.m_sp); }
    A& operator=(A other)
    {
        swap(other);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Comment: And `std::swap` will also call the move constructor, which calls `std::swap` again.